# i can't upload binary to itunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I take about 1 month trying to upload my application but all to no avail. I called Apple, I followed the steps in your emails asking me to solve the problem but nothing works. I have tried everything, up from XCODE Version 7.1 (7B91b) and also from Application Loader 3.0  but again, nothing works, within seconds you have uploaded my application I get this:

In the image out compilations I uploaded to iTunes Connect, all with an exclamation point in red and says "There was an error importing the compilation"

[image]

Comment: Can you please translate the error message? What does it say?

Comment: I can't see your image; if there's an error message in it, it's worth copying it as text and editing it into your question; it'll mean that people with the same problem can find this question by searching, too.

Comment: Ready, I edited the issue and have made the mistake!

Comment: What was written in the E-Mails? You should've received one for every binary that was automatically rejected.

Comment: I *think* this is the equivalent of the English language error "There was an error importing this build", which might help you search.

Comment: I have not received any email to reject binary emails that have been sent and received are steps for the solution supiesta my case. I sent photos, evidence, xcode versions, browsers etc. Even when support call I was told that the mistake was on their part but they could not fix it and that I should send other compilations to solve it. But I have not got the solution. I have seen many people it's happened, but solved in different ways and none have worked for me.